# How to redirect two different Django applications on the same server with same url but different paths?

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I have two Django applications running on the same server in Docker containers.
App1 is on website.com/ using localhost:9595
and App2 other is on website.com/app2. localhost:9696

Problem begins when I go to website.com/app2/something
where it redirects me to website.com/something which doesn't exist instead of going to website.com/app2/something.

I can fix it in NGINX by adding:

```
/something/{
proxy_pass localhost:9696/something/
}
```

But then I have to do it for every subpage of my application2.

Comment: Could you please add the nginx config?

Comment: @Andromeda I will

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just proxy_pass the /app2/ path?

```
/app1/ {
    proxy_pass ...django app1 wsgi here...
}

/app2/ {
        proxy_pass ...your django app2 wsgi here...
}
```

Comment: `/ {
    proxy_pass ...django app1 wsgi here...
}



/app2/ {
        proxy_pass ...your django app2 wsgi here...
}` 
It's like this. Problem is that when I go to example.com/app2/something, for some reason it redirects me to example.com/something